# overflow property issue with dropdown and bar

Tags: css

I have following CSS that shows for top navigation bar with a drop-down menu.

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: white;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999px;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #139BF7;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <ul id="authdropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <li> <a href="/profile"> Edit Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="/viewprofile">View Profile</a></li>
    <li> <a href="/UserSettings">  Orders</a></li>
    <li><a href="/UserSettings">Payments</a></li>
    <li><a href="/UserSettings">Favourites</a></li>
    <li><a href="/UserSettings"> Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">Sign Out</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

It shows bar background if put `overflow: hidden` dropdown not appeared outside of div and only first element shows.

[image]

However when I put `overflow: visible` a drop-down shows all elements but background gets invisible.

[image]

So what solution to show background with dropdown elements appears

Comment: kindly post a working snippet so we can help!

Comment: this means that you are using float element in the dropdown, consider use something else (inline-block, flex, etc)

Comment: add your HTML part also

Comment: as expected, you are using float element ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif please provide solution as relevant code snipped added